# SSMSBoost intellisense not working?

Tags: sql-server, ssms

SSMS Version `17.9.1`

It looks like the intellisense may not be working? Shouldn't it auto complete `Select` etc? Also, it looks like the intellisense is from SSMS itself (doesn't work that great)

[image]

I've checked the Intellisense setting and it's there just fine, also put the cache size on `unlimited`

[image]

Comment: This question is about the third party SSMS extension [SSMSBoost](https://www.ssmsboost.com). SSMS support support for extensions is notoriously flaky. Many folks (myself included) have given up on them for this reason. Have you tried contacting support from the vendor?

Comment: @LowlyDBA-JohnMcCall yeah I tried all that, didn't work, the post is also from 2011 and I tried recent posts too

Comment: Try the newest 18.8 SSMS. At the very least, that'll *also* install Azure Data Studio which actually has somewhat reliable Intellisense (compared to SSMS).

Comment: @LowlyDBA-JohnMcCall installed but same behavior: https://i.imgur.com/2QIa6s6.gif (with SSMSboost and without)

Comment: Trying out SQL Complete now, looks like the intellisense works on that

Comment: I have sent you an e-mail via @support. (Intellisense is not a functionality of SSMSBoost).

Answer (score 0):

Please, try to reset Intellisense Cache:

```
CTRL+SHFT+R
```

But Intellisense completes object names not sql statement like SELECT.